# Can I select text by clicking on the linum column in emacs?

Tags: emacs

**See my answer below**

The next paragraph is here to keep the bot happy

T-bone bresaola boudin pork chop, ullamco non voluptate qui venison fugiat rump pastrami nulla in drumstick. Nostrud ham pariatur, laboris brisket duis aliqua elit leberkäse. Capicola ut pork pork belly, meatball veniam filet mignon tongue drumstick flank ut proident ad. T-bone shankle culpa tongue nulla dolore biltong, pancetta nostrud ut. Sed beef sirloin occaecat, brisket anim sint. Culpa strip steak exercitation ea aute shoulder. Ribeye shoulder chuck, strip steak ground round sed brisket sirloin consequat capicola beef leberkäse shank cillum.

Comment: you should be able to answer; [it doesn't require any rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts). Try to click on `Answer Your Question` button. Rules for self-answers might have changed.

Comment: You can self-answer, but you need to wait 8 hours, unless your rep is >= 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you can add to your .emacs
When you click on the margin and release the cursor, it selects the corresponding lines.
Tested with gnu emacs 23.3

update:Bugfix

```
(defvar *linum-mdown-line* nil)

(defun line-at-click ()
  (save-excursion
    (let ((click-y (cdr (cdr (mouse-position))))
          (line-move-visual-store line-move-visual))
      (setq line-move-visual t)
      (goto-char (window-start))
      (next-line (1- click-y))
      (setq line-move-visual line-move-visual-store)
      ;; If you are using tabbar substitute the next line with
      ;; (line-number-at-pos))))
      (1+ (line-number-at-pos)))))

(defun md-select-linum ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-line (line-at-click))
  (set-mark (point))
  (setq *linum-mdown-line* (line-number-at-pos)))

(defun mu-select-linum ()
  (interactive)
  (when *linum-mdown-line*
    (let (mu-line)
      (setq mu-line (line-at-click))
      (if (> mu-line *linum-mdown-line*)
          (progn
            (goto-line *linum-mdown-line*)
            (set-mark (point))
            (goto-line mu-line)
            (end-of-line))
          (progn
            (goto-line *linum-mdown-line*)
            (set-mark (line-end-position))
            (goto-line mu-line)
            (beginning-of-line)))
      (setq *linum-mdown* nil))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<left-margin> <down-mouse-1>") 'md-select-linum)
(global-set-key (kbd "<left-margin> <mouse-1>") 'mu-select-linum)
(global-set-key (kbd "<left-margin> <drag-mouse-1>") 'mu-select-linum)
```